# How do I use "for" for this case

Tags: kotlin

I need this function to look in a file for a certain day, then say for each flight how many people are there, in the same day.
So far I managed to get it to say how many people there are per day, but im struggling to get it to say how many people are on each flight per day.

```
fun interval(reserves: ArrayList<Reserves>, dayInferior: Int, daySuperior: Int) {
    var count = dayInferior
    var person: Int
    for (reserve in reserves) {
        person = 0
        for (reserve in reserves) {
            if (reserve.day == count && reserve.day <= daySuperior) {
                person++
            }
        }
        if (count <= daySuperior) {
            println("${reserve.numFlight} Day $count has $person")
        }
        count++
    }

}

class Reserves {
    var numCc: Int?
    var name: String
    var numFlight: String
    var day: Int

    constructor(numCc: Int?, name: String, numFlight: String, day: Int) {
        this.numCc = numCc
        this.name = name
        this.numFlight = numFlight
        this.day = day
    }
}


fun readFileReserves(fileNameInput: String): ArrayList<Reserves> {
    val reserves: ArrayList<Reserves> = ArrayList()
    val lines = File(fileNameInput).readLines()

    for (line in lines) {
        val parts = line.split(':')
        val numCc = parts[0].toIntOrNull()
        val name = parts[1]
        val numFlight = parts[2]
        val day = parts[3].toIntOrNull()

        if (day == null || numCc == null) {
            println("Invalid day")
        } else {
            val r = Reserves(numCc, name, numFlight, day)
            reserves.add(r)
        }

    }
    return reserves
}
```

Comment: Would probably be helpful if you named the variables English instead of Spanish :-)

Comment: I will edit, thanks, btw its not spanish, uts portuguese haha

Comment: If you're asking about a Kotlin `for` statement, why did you tag `java`? They are entirely different languages, and you're asking about language syntax.

Comment: Okay sorry, can’t tell the difference 

Comment: Could you please add info i.e. properties about Reserves

Comment: Added a class and other function important for better understanding

Comment: What numCc and name refer to?

Comment: numCc, is the citizen number of the person and name is the person's name

Comment: the code of `Reserves`is redundant (see [this](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#constructors)), you can replace it with `class Reserves(var numCc: Int?, var name: String, var numFlight: String, var day: Int)`

Comment: What does `dayInferior` and `daySuperior` mean?

Comment: the user says the interval of days in each he wants to know the info, so 'dayInferior' is for the day "smallest" day and 'daySuperior' for the "biggest day" @Joshua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume @Jocas means `interval` to get the count of `Reserves` between `dayInferior` and `daySuperior`.

```
fun interval(reserves: List<Reserves>, dayInferior: Int, daySuperior: Int) {
    val map = mapReserves(reserves)
    for(day in dayInferior..daySuperior) {
        map.forEach {
            val reservesName = it.key.first
            val reservesDay = it.key.second
            val reservesCount = it.value.count()                
            if (reservesDay == day)
                print("$reservesName has $reservesCount on day passengers $day")
        }
    }        
}

fun mapReserves(reserves: List<Reserves>): Map<Pair<String, Int>, List<Reserves>> {
    val map = mutableMapOf<Pair<String, Int>, MutableList<Reserves>>()
    reserves.forEach { 
        val key = it.numFlight to it.day
        val list = map[key] ?: mutableListOf()
        list.add(it)
        map[key] = list
    }
    return map
}

// This is how you write in Kotlin. Your style is Java.
class Reserves(var numCc: Int, var name: String, var numFlight: String, var day: Int)

// Use abstraction List and MutableList instead of ArrayList 
fun readFileReserves(fileNameInput: String): List<Reserves> {
    val reserves = mutableListOf<Reserves>()
    val lines = File(fileNameInput).readLines()

    for (line in lines) {
        val parts = line.split(":")
        val numCc = parts[0].toIntOrNull()
        val name = parts[1]
        val numFlight = parts[2]
        val day = parts[3].toIntOrNull()

        if (day == null || numCc == null) {
            println("Invalid day")
        } else {
            val r = Reserves(numCc, name, numFlight, day)
            reserves.add(r)
        }

    }
    return reserves
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Thank you! I'm still very new into this so I have a lot to learn. But I still can't figure out how to make the program tell how many people are on each flight in each day. @Joshua

Comment: @Jocas Where can I find number of people on each reserves? `numCc`?

Comment: No, there is no var that says how many people are on each reserves, I have it in a way that it counts how many different people or on each day. @Joshua

Comment: @Jocas Then, how is it different from `interval` when `dayInferior` = `daySuperior`?

Comment: When `dayInferior` = `daySuperior` it only counts how many people are on that day. @Joshua

Comment: @Jocas Oh, you mean a `Map<Int, Int>` where the key is the day and value  is the count?

Comment: Im confused haha, but basically the `dayInferior` transforms into `count` then it looks on the file and every time it finds a person with a flight in that day it adds `person++`, after that it prints the day that was transformed into `count` and after `count++`and basically `dayInferior` goes one day up and verify's it until reaches `daySuperior`. @Joshua

Comment: @Jocas I have updated the answer. See if that what you are looking for.

Comment: It does the same as the one I created but way more simply :D, although it still doesn't say how many people are on each flight in each day. The output should be something like this: "Flight SZ23 has 2 passengers on day 2. Flight CD78 has 2 passengers on day 2....". @Joshua

Comment: that's pretty close :D, thanks, but one last thing, this is the output now: "TP23 has 2 passengers on day 1.
TP23 has 2 passengers on day 2.
VN453 has 0 passengers on day 1.
VN453 has 2 passengers on day 2." is there a way to verify them by day so it doesn't puts them together by name and it doesnt show flights that don't exist? @Joshua

Comment: @Jocas Can you update your question with expected input and output

Comment: the expected output is: TP23 has 2 passengers on day 1. VN453 has 2 passengers on day 2. TP23 has 2 passengers on day 2. @Joshua

Comment: @Jocas I have updated the answer. Because of you design, I don't have a way to know a flight that have no reserve or it just not exist. I decided to show it anyway.

Comment: Now it's fine, it doesnt show any flights with no passengers but how do I make it so the output is ordered by day instead of name of flight? @Joshua

Comment: @Jocas Updated again

Comment: can you clarify what is the "it" like where it is `it.numFlight`, I have been looking at it but can't figure it out @Joshua

Comment: @Jocas Accept the answer if you thinks it is fine =). [`it` is the  implicit name of a single parameter.](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter) This mean if a function literal has only one parameter, its default name is `it`. I cannot describe to details in comment. You can read the official document on the link above.

Comment: Oh sorry, I’m new to this but did it now :). Okay, thank you again, I Will read that now. @Joshua

Comment: Hey, in your solution, can you tell me what makes `dayInferior` and `daySuperior` not be null? I had a previous verification with `if` and `else` before, and now it says irrelevant because `dayInferior == null`is always false, although I can't figure out what makes it do that. Thanks in advance. @Joshua